# Is it easier to find $a^2-8c=b^2$ than $a^2-c=b^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

I found a way to factor numbers if I find:

$$a^2-8c=b^2$$

- Where $c$ is the number I want to factor

Is it easier than searching for the next equation?

$$a^2-c=b^2$$

Comment: What is your method?

Comment: @martycohen I make a deal with you. Show me that it's matter and I show you the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you have
$a^2-c^2 = b^2$,
then you can use
the known result
about solutions to
$u^2+v^2 = w^2$:
there exists
$m$ and $n$ such that
$u = m^2-n^2$,
$v = 2mn$,
and
$w = m^2+n^2$.

For
$a^2-8c^2 = b^2$,
I am not aware of a similar result,
though one might exist.

In both cases,
you can look at the
factorization of
$a^2-b^2
=(a-b)(a+b)
$.
The presence of the $8$
would force
both
$a+b$ and $a-b$
to be even
(since of one of them is even
the other is also, and similarly for odd),
and would also force
the power of two
that divides one of them
to be even
and the other to be odd.

In other words,
once you have
$c^2 = a^2-b^2$
or
$8c^2 = a^2-b^2$,
your factoring job
is essentially over,
unless you want the
complete factorization
of very large numbers.

Comment: very large numbers is indeed my need, but I do not see you answering the question: Does it helps me by any how?. Will it make the factoring process easier by having such formula?

Comment: $a^2-8c^2=b^2\iff (\frac{a}{b})^2-2(\frac{2c}{b})^2=1$. This is [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). To solve it, first find the first non-trivial solution $(x_1,y_1)=\left(\pm\frac{a}{b},\pm\frac{2c}{b}\right)$ and all the other solutions are generated by $x_{n}+\sqrt{2}y_n=(x_1+\sqrt{2}y_1)^n$.

Comment: @user314 The initial division by $b^2$ doesn't work to reduce it to an ordinary Pell, and for some $b$ there may not be solutions to $a^2-8c^2=b^2.$

Comment: @coffeemath This method will only find the solutions $a,b,c$ that also satisfy $b\mid a$ and $b\mid 2c$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @user314 $133^2 - 8*43*47 = 39^2$ does it helps?

Comment: If $8c^2 = 133^2-39^2 = (133-39)(133+39) = 94*172 = (2*47)*(4*43)$, so $c^2 = 47*43$ which is not a square.

Comment: @user314: You do not get a Pell equation, since that requires the values to be integers.

Comment: @martycohen oh, I am sorry, I wrote it wrong. Please look at it now

Comment: @user314 I only meant one cannot divide through for integers and that the usual Pell has right side $1$. However I was wrong in saying $a^2-8c^2=b^2$ might not have solutions, since e.g. $3^2-8\cdot1^1=1$ could be multiplied through by any $b^2.$ [I don't know if that's valuable for this factoring method...]

Comment: @coffeemath I had mistake in the question. its $c$ and not $c^2$, can you find solution of obituary $c$?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman But if you seek to factor $c$ and already have solved $a^2-8c=b^2$ then $8c=(b-a)(b+a)$ is a factorization of $8c,$ which seems to me about the same as the job of factoring $c$. On the other hand if $c=u\cdot v$ one can get to $8c=8uv$ and provided $u,v$ are both odd (which would be the case when factoring $c$ since obvious factors already removed) one can go backward and get $a,b$. I don't see an advantage to using the approach of going through the step of solving $a^2-8c=b^2.$

Comment: @coffeemath in case of $a^2 - 8c = b^2$ $a,b$ are not the factors, but can help me to easily obtain those. I also know that $\sqrt{a^2-8c}<\sqrt{c}$

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman GIven a solution to $a^2-8c=b^2,$ does your method provide anything other than a factorization of $c$ depending on the relation $8c=(a-b)(a+b)$? That is, do you get directly a factorization of $c$ without the $8$ in front? It would help anyone trying to answer if you included your method of factoring, maybe with an example of a relatively small $c$ to be factored.

Comment: @coffeemath I posted new [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128027/integer-factorization-what-is-the-meaning-of-a2-kc-b2) about this idea where I also explain how I got this.