# Integer factorization: What is the meaning of $d^2 - kc = e^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, factorial, prime-factorization

I found an interesting behavior when placing the [integer factorization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) in to geometry, I call it **pyramid factoring**.

Lets assume we have $c$ boxes and we want to order them in to rectangle. The rectangle sides needs to be 
$$x>=y$$
$$xy=c$$

Here is an illustration of $23*19$ rectangle
[image]

Now look what happened when I cut a pyramid from the bottom.

[image]

And adding half of it to the rite side

[image]

Lets call the pyramid height $a$ and the reminder $b$, such that:
$$x =2a-1$$ 
$$y =a+b$$

So now we can say:

$$c = (2a-1)(a+b)$$

And if we extract $a$, we will get

$$a = \frac{1-2b+\sqrt{4b^2 + 4b + 8c + 1}}{4}$$

*I ignored the negative solution here*. But we can keep going. Lets see for what $b$ values the determinate will be an integer value?
$$4b^2 + 4b + 8c + 1 = d^2$$

- $d$ is the determinant integer value we are searching for

When extracting $b$ we are getting

$$b = \frac{-1+\sqrt{d^2 - 8c}}{2}$$

And as before, lets see when the determinant is a positive value?

$$d^2 - 8c = e^2$$

And in our example

$$61^2-8*19*23 =15^2$$

Solving this equation is as hard as finding the factors of $c$, or at least this is what I though...

What we know about $d$?

- it's easy can be seen that $d$ is a odd value

Also if we compare $d$ to $a$ we get the next thing

$$a = \frac{1-2b+d}{4}$$
$$d = 2(a + b) - (2a-1)-2$$
$$d = 2y - x - 2$$

So we can say

$$0<2y-d-1<y<=\sqrt{c}<=x$$
$$0<d<3\sqrt{c}$$

And considering all we can say

$$8c<d^2<9c$$

I been lucky to find this equation, so I been trying to see if there are such relationships with different multiplier of $c$, and I found few examples for that

$$d^2 - kc = e^2$$
$$kc<d^2<(k+1)c$$

for $k = 32$

$$c = 423107= 523* 809$$
$$3710^2 - kc = 474^2$$

for $k = 15$

$$c = 590917= 643* 919$$
$$2986^2 - kc = 229^2$$

So what is the rule here? How can I select a multiplier? And how can I extract the x,y  from it if I find $d$?

Comment: $a^2-kc=b^2 \iff a^2-b^2=kc \iff (a+b)(a-b)=kc$

Comment: I really don't want to discourage you from attempting to solve interesting problems, but you have been trying to solve, via fairly rudimentary techniques, a problem which has stymied tens of thousands of very clever mathematicians for centuries. You are probably not going to find a high school math technique for factoring large numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews May be. But I asked some pretty good questions, like this one. And I am not getting answers. It could be that people did not think of all of it...

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman How do you define "good?" :)

Comment: For instance, there is a huge amount of information in this question, so that it is hard to find the question. It is more a dissertation than a question.

Comment: For example when you *finally* get to the question, you ask for "how can I select a multiplier?" What multiplier? $k$? You have never once used the word "multiplier" reference to any variable. It's not clear what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are studying a version of [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation):

> Around AD 250, Diophantus considered the equation
>
> $a^2 x^2 + c = y^2 $,
> where a and c are fixed numbers and x and y are the variables to be solved for. This equation is different in form from Pell's equation but equivalent to it. Diophantus solved the equation for (a,c) equal to (1,1), (1,−1), (1,12), and (3,9)

Pell's equation (in your version and in the standard version) has been studied extensively and has numerous interesting geometric and number-theoretic properties, including the ability to use one or more solutions to get more solutions. For more background, read:
[http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/nti/chap5.pdf](http://www2.math.ou.edu/%7Ekmartin/nti/chap5.pdf)

and this page with some nifty tools:
http://www.math.mtu.edu/mathlab/COURSES/holt/dnt/pell4.html

Answer (score 0):

If $k = 1$, you've got:
$$d = \frac{c+1}{2}$$
$$e = \frac{c-1}{2}$$

As well as:
$$d = \frac{x+y}{2}$$
$$e = \frac{x-y}{2}$$

More generally, for $k = f1*f2*f3...fn$:
Make two numbers $m_1$ and $m_2$ as products of all factors of $k$ and $c$.

Taking appropriate $m_1$ and $m_2$, such that $m_1m_2 = kc$ then:
$$d = \frac{m_1+m_2}{2}$$
$$e = \frac{m1-m2}{2}$$

For example, taking $c = 590917$ and $k = 15$, we can make $m_1 = 643*5$ and $m2 = 919*3$.
From this we get:
$$d = \frac{643*5 + 919*3}{2} = 2986$$
$$e = \frac{643*5 - 919*3}{2} = 229$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For future answers I recommend using LaTeX or mathjax for formatting. 

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference